# What is meant by "decimal fraction" ? Why have rationals been referred to as periodic and irrationals as non periodic?

Tags: real-analysis

My book mentions " Any decimal fraction, terminating or non terminating, is called a real number.

Periodic decimal fractions are called rational numbers and non periodic decimal fractions are irrational numbers."

Comment: It's not a good rigorous definition but it just means any number given in decimal form, eg 0.2345231... with any sequence of digits, possibly infinite.

Comment: If you have a fraction of two whole numbers, such as $\frac {8}{17}$ and you do long division to find its decimal expansion, it will either terminate (and end in an infinite number of $0$s) or eventually you will start repeating values (because there are only a finite number of possible remainders and once you repeat one you get in an infinite loop).  Because the decimal repeats we say it is "periodic" (periodic things repeat on a times cycle). Irrational number are *not* fractions of whole numbers and therefore can *not* repeat or terminate.

Comment: In my opinion and from an advanced viewpoint your book does things backwards.  Numbers (such as $\pi, \sqrt 2, \frac 8{17}$) come first and decimals come later.  The *definition* of a rational is it can be a fraction between two whole numbers.  That its decimal either terminates or repeats is a *result*, not the definition. The *definition* of irrational is any number that is not rational.  That it's decimal never terminates or gets into a repeating pattern is a *result*. A lot of books introduce it your books way and ... it's okay, I think.  ... But it's not technically correct.

Comment: Also, it would be better to say "eventually periodic"; a rational number might have arbitrary decimal digits before it is periodic.  Calculate $1/300$.  But, as fleablood says, this is usually regarded as a property of rational numbers and not the definition.